# In Ubuntu 9.10, how do I disable the "Your battery may be old or broken" notification on log in?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, power-management, battery, notifications

Every time I log in, I get this message. It's helpful to see once, but I don't need to see it every time I log in. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix this by opening `gconf-editor`, and setting the key `/apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity` to false.

Comment: You can get directly to the key by pressing ALT-F2 and entering: `gconf-editor /apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity`

Comment: @Smiley: Alternatively, you can just run `gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity "False"`

Answer (score 2):

It seems it has something to do with the [GNOME Power Manager](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/index.html.en) settings.

Comment: @Matthew - Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

This also works in 10.04, as an aside.